# Stopping a clip path flashlight effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this code below I use clip path and the mouse to create a flashlight effect with your mouse and you can use it to look around an image and this works perfectly fine.

However I'm wondering how to create a JavaScript function to stop this happening and just display the whole image without the flashlight effect. This would be attached to the button turn on light.

I have tried and the closest I've got is that it shows the image fine but goes back to the flashlight after I move the mouse.

Any code on how to stop this and a bit of explanation how its stoping the effect would be great

So I want the flashlight effect to stop working when I click the button

```
<html>
        <head> 
            <style>        
.image {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  border:5px solid black;
  cursor:none;
}
.image .torch {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  background:url("back.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;  
  clip-path:circle(30% at 0% 0%);
    
}          
            </style>
            
<script>
       
function moveTorch(event){
var torch = document.getElementsByClassName("torch")[0];
torch.style.clipPath = `circle(30% at ${event.offsetX}px ${event.offsetY}px)`;
                            }
function turnOn(){

}

</script>                
</head>
    
<body>        
 <div class="image" onmousemove="moveTorch(event)">
                        
<div class="torch">
<button onclick="turnOn();">Turn on Light</button>
></div>
                  
</div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure I understood. You want the flashlight effect to occur only when you click on the button?

Comment: sorry I want the flashlight to stop occurring when I click the button. Will edit the post to say that sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>        
         .image {
         width:600px;
         height:400px;
         border:5px solid black;
         cursor:none;
         }
         .image .torch {
         width:600px;
         height:400px;
         background:url("back.jpg") center no-repeat;
         background-size:cover;  
         clip-path:circle(30% at 0% 0%);
         }          
      </style>
      <script>
         var flashLightOn = false;
                
         function moveTorch(event){
             if (!flashLightOn) {
                 var torch = document.getElementsByClassName("torch")[0];
                 torch.style.clipPath = `circle(30% at ${event.offsetX}px ${event.offsetY}px)`;
             }
                                     }
         function turnOn(){
             flashLightOn = true;
             var torch = document.getElementsByClassName("torch")[0];
             torch.style.clipPath = "none";
         }
         
      </script>                
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="image" onmousemove="moveTorch(event)">
         <div class="torch">
            <button onclick="turnOn();">Turn on Light</button>
            >
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Basically it stores the flash liste state (on/off) in a variable. When on, the event that makes the flash light effect does nothing (`if flashLightOn` statement).

When you click on the button, the flashLightOn value is set to false, and the style of the "torch"  is reset to default to disable the light effect.